# What is the difference between using '+' (plus) and ';' (semicolon) in -exec command?

Tags: find

I'm wondering to know that what difference is the between using `+` and `;` at the end of `-exec` command when I use in `find` command?

```
find .... -exec ... \;
```

VS

```
find .... -exec ... +
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`-exec ... \;` will run one item after another. So if you have three files, the exec line will run three times.

`-exec ... {} +` is for commands that can take more than one file at a time (eg `cat`, `stat`, `ls`). The files found by `find` are chained together like an `xargs` command. This means less forking out and for small operations, can mean a substantial speedup.

Here's a performance demo catting 10,000 empty files.

```bsh
$ mkdir testdir
$ touch testdir/{0000..9999}

$ time find testdir/ -type f -exec cat {} \;
real    0m8.622s
user    0m0.452s
sys     0m8.288s

$ time find testdir/ -type f -exec cat {} +
real    0m0.052s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.037s
```

Again this only works on commands that can take multiple filenames. You can work out if your command is like that by looking at its manpage. Here's the synopsis from `man cat`:

```
SYNOPSIS
       cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

The ellipsis on `[FILE]...` means it can take more than one file.

`+` can only be used on single commands and you must have exactly one `{}` in the line. `\;` can operate with multiple zero-to-many groups.

Comment: Example: with `\;`, the executed command would be `cat 1; cat 2; cat 3`. With `+`, the executed command would be `cat 1 2 3`.

Comment: AFAIK, the `+` is not POSIX, so may not be available on non-Linux systems. Not a concern if you never leave the platform, but good to know if you ever have to use Solaris. :)

Comment: Oh nice, thanks for the info. I typically `-exec <command> {} ';'` because its easier on my typing (I can touch type but I don't exactly have the best technique).

Comment: @SimonRichter: No, `-exec ... {} +` is POSIX. See: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_05

Comment: @SimonRichter The `-exec ... {} +` extension was [suggested for inclusion into POSIX specs in 2001](https://collaboration.opengroup.org/external/pasc.org/interpretations/unofficial/db/p1003.2/pasc-1003.2-210.html) and ratified into POSIX issue 6 in 2004. It's possible the version of Solaris you're used to is older than that POSIX standard (or just targets an earlier version).