# Script to put filenames from the working directory into a text file so commands can be run on them

Tags: scripts

I want to make a script that puts filenames from the working directory (with a specific extension) in text file with some additional strings:

For example, if I'm interested in files with extension `i` and files in my directory are:

```
1.b  1.i  2.i  2.z 3.i
```

I want to make a text file like:

```
command_1
command_2 1.i 1.o && command_2 2.i 2.o && command_2 3.i 3.o &
```

Comment: Will the rest of the script be same? You just need the files of successive names from current directory to be replaced as the first arguments of the successions of `command_2` ?

Comment: yes, also I need  put the same filename but with other extension ("o") as the second argument, and etc for the next file.

Comment: What is your final goal? Just making a text file in the exact format given or running commands ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution.

Skip making a text file and just made a script to execute multiple files in a folder

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.i*
do
  [[ "${file##*.}" =~ fchk ]] && continue
  qchem "$file" "${file%.*}".out 
done

clear
echo "DONE!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your answer you don't really want to create a text file but just search for files and process them. You can use the `find` command for that, for example to rename all files ending in `.i` replacing `i` by `o` do:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.i" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0/i/o}"' "{}" \;
```

#### Explanations

- `-maxdepth 1` stay in the current directory
- `-type f` search files only
- `-name "*.i"` search files ending in `.i`
- `-exec` execute the following command on the file, `{}` is substituted by the file name, needs to be finished with `\;`
- `bash -c` start a subshell running the following commands, by adding `"{}"` we give it the filename as argument 0
- `mv "$0" "${0/i/o}"` rename the file by substituting `i` by `o` – just an example of course, can be replaced by any (chain of) commands you like
- `\;` finishes the `-exec` option

For commands that can take more than one file at a time you can substitute `\;` by `+` to chain the arguments, see [What is the difference between using '+' (plus) and ';' (semicolon) in -exec command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558817/what-is-the-difference-between-using-plus-and-semicolon-in-exec-com).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative if for some reason you want to use a file to store the list of files:

```
ls *.i  > input.txt
for F in $(cat /path/to/input.txt) ; do
...
done;
```

or, if you have spaces in your filenames

```
while read F  ; do
...
done </path/to/input.txt
```