# remove file but exclude all files in a list

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, rm

I need to cleanup a folder periodically.
I get a filelist which contains text, which files are allowed.
Now I have to delete all files which are not in this file.

Example:

**`dont-delete.txt`:**

```
dontdeletethisfile.txt
reallyimportantfile.txt
neverdeletethis.txt
important.txt
```

My folder do clean-up contains this as example:

**`ls /home/me/myfolder2tocleanup/`:**

```
dontdeletethisfile.txt
reallyimportantfile.txt
neverdeletethis.txt
important.txt
this-can-be-deleted.txt
also-waste.txt
never-used-it.txt
```

So this files should be deleted:

```
this-can-be-deleted.txt
also-waste.txt
never-used-it.txt
```

I search something to create a delete command with an option to exclude some files provided by file.

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: I hope you're not his teacher. lol

Comment: @gujarat  We're not free homework service, so the comment is justified. As for the question itself, it may be useful to others, so it's open so far.

Comment: @Serg I'm totally agree with you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `rm` command is commented out so that you can check and verify that it's working as needed.  Then just un-comment that line.

The `check directory` section will ensure you don't accidentally run the script from the wrong directory and clobber the wrong files.

You can remove the `echo deleting` line to run silently.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/me/myfolder2tocleanup/

# Exit if the directory isn't found.
if (($?>0)); then
    echo "Can't find work dir... exiting"
    exit
fi

for i in *; do
    if ! grep -qxFe "$i" filelist.txt; then
        echo "Deleting: $i"
        # the next line is commented out.  Test it.  Then uncomment to removed the files
        # rm "$i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I edited your code to avoid [useless use of `ls`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#ls) and the useless capturing of the output of `grep` if all you want to know is whether there was a match or not. I also used fixed-string patterns to avoid escaping issues.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks for the contribution.  However, when you changed the `while` loop to a `for` loop you inadvertently changed the `iteration key` from `i` to `f`. in the declaration, which broke the code.  I fixed it.

Comment: Oops, force of habit. I tend to abbreviate shell variable names for file names as `f`. ;-P (…and +1 for your answer which I forgot earlier.)

Answer (score 11):

This python script can do this:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
no_remove = set()
with open('./dont-delete.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
         no_remove.add(line.strip())

for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if f not in no_remove:
        print('unlink:' + f ) 
        #os.unlink(f)
```

Important part is to uncomment the `os.unlink()` function.

**NOTE**:  add this script and `dont-delete.txt` to your `dont-delete.txt` so that they both are on the list,  and keep them in the same directory.

Comment: I changed your code to use a `set` instead of a list for O(1) instead of O(n) look-up in the second part.

Comment: thanks for your help, i'm normally a windows guy, but python seams too be cool =)

Comment: @stefan83: Python runs just as well on Windows.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a one-liner:

```
comm -2 -3 <(ls) <(sort dont_delete) | tail +2 | xargs -p rm
```

1. `ls` prints all files in the current directory (in sorted order)
2. `sort dont_delete` prints all the files we don't want to delete in sorted order
3. the `<()` operator turns a string into a file-like object
4. The `comm` commands compares two pre-sorted files and prints out lines on which they differ
5. using the `-2 -3` flags causes `comm` to only print lines contained in the first file but not the second, which will be the list of files that are safe to delete
6. the `tail +2` call is just to remove the heading of the `comm` output, which contains the name of the input file
7. Now we get a list of files to delete on standard out. We pipe this output to `xargs` which will turn the output stream into a list of arguments for `rm`. The `-p` option forces `xargs` to ask for confirmation before executing.

Comment: thx for your help, now I have my solution !

Comment: @gardenhead, I tired your code but it removes all files in the directory and keep only the first and the last file in the dont-delete list. do you have any idea for this problem? thanks in advance.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, as if the keep list is of length M and you have N files to filter, this solution is O(MlgM + N)

Answer (score 2):

FWIW it looks like you can do this natively in `zsh`, using the `(+cmd)` glob qualifier.

To illustrate, let's start with some files

```
 % ls
bar  baz  bazfoo  keepfiles.txt  foo  kazoo
```

and a whitelist file

```
 % cat keepfiles.txt
foo
kazoo
bar
```

First, read the whitelist into an array:

```
 % keepfiles=( "${(f)$(< keepfiles.txt)}" )
```

or perhaps better

```
 % zmodload zsh/mapfile
 % keepfiles=( ${(f)mapfile[./keepfiles.txt]} )
```

(the equivalent of bash's `mapfile` builtin - or its synonym `readarray`). Now we can check whether a key (filename) exists in the array using `${keepfiles[(I)filename]}` which returns 0 if no match is found:

```
 % print ${keepfiles[(I)foo]}
1
 % print ${keepfiles[(I)baz]}
0
 %
```

We can use this to make a function that returns `true` if there are no matches for `$REPLY` in the array:

```
% nokeep() { (( ${keepfiles[(I)$REPLY]} == 0 )); }
```

Finally, we use this function as a qualifier in our command:

```
 % ls *(+nokeep)
baz  bazfoo  keepfiles.txt
```

or, in your case

```
 % rm -- *(+nokeep)
```

(You'll likely want to add the name of the whitelist file itself to the whitelist.)

Answer (score 2):

Unless the output of `ls /home/me/myfolder2tocleanup/` exceeds the **maximum shell argument limit** `ARG_MAX` which is around **2MB** for Ubuntu, I would suggest the following.

---

A one line command implementation that will do the job, would be as follows:

1. Copy the `dont-delete.txt` file to the directory containing the files to be deleted like so:

```
cp dont-delete.txt /home/me/myfolder2tocleanup/
```

2. `cd` to the directory containing the files to be deleted like so:

```
cd /home/me/myfolder2tocleanup/
```

3. Do a dry-run to test the command and make it print the names of the files that it detects as to be deleted without actually deleting them, like so:

```
ls -p | grep -v / | sed 's/\<dont-delete.txt\>//g' | sort | comm -3 - <(sort dont-delete.txt) | xargs echo | tr " " "\n"
```

4. If you are satisfied with the output, delete the files by running the command like so:

```
ls -p | grep -v / | sed 's/\<dont-delete.txt\>//g' | sort | comm -3 - <(sort dont-delete.txt) | xargs rm
```

---

Explaination:

- `ls -p` will list all the *files and directories* in the current directory and the option `-p` will add a `/` to the directory names.
- `grep -v /` will exclude directories by removing all items containing a `/` in their names.
- `sed 's/\<dont-delete.txt\>//g'`will exclude the `dont-delete.txt` file, so it does not get deleted in the process.
- `sort` will, just to make sure, sort the remaining output of `ls`.
- `comm -3 - <(sort dont-delete.txt)` will sort the `dont-delete.txt` file, compare it to the sorted output of `ls` and exclude filenames
  that exist in both.
- `xargs rm` will remove all the remaining filenames in the already processed output of `ls`. This means all the items in the current
  directory will be removed except for **directories**, **files listed
  in the `dont-delete.txt` file** and **the `dont-delete.txt` file
  itself**

In the dry-run part:

- `xargs echo` will print the files that should be removed.
- `tr " " "\n"` will translate spaces into new lines for easier readability.

---

**Notice:**

In some cases [parsing the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) might be better avoided.

Comment: i tried thi, instead of files i have folders and sub-folder with files inside. It didn't work why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your bash shell has the `extglob` `shopt` set to on, here is a somewhat more conservative alternative:

```
rm !($(tr \\n \| < keep.txt))
```

(...accompanying @gardenhead's otherwise excellent comm suggestion!)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest to use [`rsync` solution posted here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1202917/283843); else use below solution with an exceptional condition mentioned.

Assuming there is no whitespace (Spaces/Tabs) in your files' listed in a file called `excludelist`, then you would do:

```
find /path/to -type f \( ! -name "excludelist" $(printf ' -a ! -name %s\n' $(< excludelist)) \)
```

Just add `-delete` to the command above to delete the files which doesn't exist in the *excludelist* file. If your find doesn't have `-delete` option you can use `rm` with `-exec` as following:

```
find /path/to -type f \( ! -name "excludelist" $(printf ' -a ! -name %s\n' $(< excludelist)) \) -exec echo rm {} \;
```

Or [using `-exec` with `+` terminator](https://askubuntu.com/q/558817/283843) instead.

```
find /path/to -type f \( ! -name "excludelist" $(printf ' -a ! -name %s\n' $(< excludelist)) \) -exec echo rm {} +
```

`echo` is just used to dry-run.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is:

```
sed -e 's/^/\.\//' dont-delete.txt > dont-delete-relative-path.txt
find . -type f -print | grep -Fxvf dont-delete-relative-path.txt | xargs -d'\n' rm
```

**Update 2018-08-07**

Example:

```
1: mkdir /tmp/delete-example && cd /tmp/delete-example
2: touch a b c d
3: echo "./a\n./b\n./dont-delete.txt\n" > dont-delete.txt
4: find . -type f -print | grep -Fxvf dont-delete.txt | xargs -d'\n' rm
```

Note after line 3 you'll have the `dont-delete.txt` file with contents:

```
./a
./b
./dont-delete.txt
```

(the leading `./` is **very important**)

The files `c` and `d` will be deleted.

Comment: I tried this with a text file of the file names separated by a newline. It ended up deleting all the files in the directory.

Comment: I guess your "keep list" was wrong.

Comment: I've added example usage.