# Invisible space when trying to remove file (but exclude all files in a list)?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, rm

I'm trying to accomplish a simple task using the excellent post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830776/remove-file-but-exclude-all-files-in-a-list): I would like to remove all files from a folder except those listed in a .txt file contained in the folder. The syntax works fine, but for some reason all files are removed - basically the script is saying that there are no correspondences between the filenames in the folder and those in the .txt file - but I can see that there are!

I thought maybe there might be some invisible white space after my file names that I cannot see (in the folder or the .txt file). But I don't think so...Is there another solution that I am not thinking of?

Comment: Try looking with the  od -c command.  You might find things like \r (return) are hidden just before the \n(newline).

Comment: You could also try this frome within the directory **  replace exclude.txt with your list file **  `ls -p | grep -v / | sed 's/\<exclude.txt\>//g' | sort | comm -3 - <(sort exclude.txt) | xargs` this will only output without removing. To remove run `ls -p | grep -v / | sed 's/\<exclude.txt\>//g' | sort | comm -3 - <(sort exclude.txt) | xargs rm`

Comment: @ubfan1 - there are indeed \n and \r at the end of each line. I removed the \r but don't I need to keep the \n to differentiate between each filename entry in the txt file?

Comment: is there a syntax error in that @raffa ?

Comment: `ls -p | grep -v / | sed 's/\<a.txt\>//g' | sort | comm -3 - <(sort a.txt) | xargs` No it is just a one line command that is easier and will do the job. I replaced exclude.txt with a.txt assuming this is the name of your list. If you run this command, it will only show you the output. If that is what you want, append `rm` after adding one space at the end to remove the files.

Comment: This leaves me with the same issue, however. It wasn't that the initial syntax was wrong, it's that there are \r and \n at the end of each line and I don't know how to structure my txt file so that each filename is read separately but also so that \n and \r are not present on each line

Comment: `\n` is okay and should be there if you run `od -c a.txt ` but `\r` is not and shouldn't be there.

Comment: I removed \r and still both approaches fail to recognize file names listed in the txt file and just remove everything.

Comment: Probably, recreate the file in `nano` editor. Copy and paste the lines one by one and press Enter once after each line except the last line no Enter after it. This should work. Good Luck

Comment: I can't manually enter. There are 13000 lines in the txt file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `a.txt` file contains hidden characters due to possibly being created or edited on other OS's like Windows.

You need to sanitize the file first in order to use it without syntax errors.

The easiest way is to use a tool called **dos2unix**. Please follow these steps to do so:

---

**Firstly:** Install `dos2unix` by opening a terminal and running the following command:

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

---

**Secondly:** Back up your `a.txt` file.

**Thirdly:** Use `dos2unix` on your file by running the following command in the terminal from within the directory containing your `a.txt` file:

```
dos2unix a.txt
```

---

**Finally:** Test your file. It should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The [script](https://askubuntu.com/a/830791/986805) you are referring to will give false positives. `for` will expand filenames literally, this means special characters will be preserved and using it as a pattern will break the matching.

Example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# the script is adapted and slightly shortened.
shopt -s nullglob
for i in a* b*; do
   grep -Fx -e "$i" exclude.txt
done
```

Output:

```
$ ls
a   'a'$'\n''b'   b   exclude.txt
```

```
$ cat exclude.txt
a
b

$ script.sh
a
a
b
b
```

A better approach would be to preserve the shell-escape.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

eval "list=( \
    $(ls --quoting-style=shell-escape !(exclude.txt) | \
        grep -vFx -f exclude.txt))"

for i in "${list[@]}"; do ls "$i"; done
```

Example:

```
$ cat exclude.txt  
'a'$'\n''b'

$ script.sh
a
b
```

```
$ cat exclude.txt  
a
b

$ script.sh
'a'$'\n''b'
```