# Creating a deamon to run .sh

Tags: bash, scripts, services

I have been playing around with it for a little while but am pretty stuck with creating a service to run a script. The script I am trying to run is as follows.

```
#!/bin/sh
while true

do

sudo bbb-record --rebuildall

sleep 300
done
```

I tried creating a daemon for this to run like:

```
[Unit]
Description=bbb-rebuild
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/sysadmin/rebuild
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target 

exit=0
```

I get the error message

```
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
Failed to start rebuild.service: Unit rebuild.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status rebuild.service' for details.

after checking status
Apr 22 16:46:55 bbb2 systemd[1]: rebuild.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 22 16:46:55 bbb2 systemd[1]: rebuild.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 22 16:46:55 bbb2 systemd[1]: rebuild.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 22 16:46:55 bbb2 systemd[1]: Stopped bbb-rebuild.
Apr 22 16:46:55 bbb2 systemd[1]: rebuild.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 22 16:46:55 bbb2 systemd[1]: Failed to start bbb-rebuild.
Apr 22 16:46:55 bbb2 systemd[1]: rebuild.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 22 16:46:55 bbb2 systemd[1]: rebuild.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Apr 22 16:47:22 bbb2 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/rebuild.service:12] Missing '='.
```

Comment: Since the service as written will run this script as root, why `sudo` in the script?

Comment: `[/etc/systemd/system/rebuild.service:12] Missing '='.` suggests a hidden characters or wrong encoding present in the file. I would suggest running `dos2unix` on the file. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1183893/968501) for information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better use [systemd-timers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) to achieve this.

Create a timer named like your systemd service `rebuild.timer`

`# nano /etc/systemd/system/rebuild.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=Start script every hour

[Timer]
OnCalendar=hourly

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Edit your script to the following

```
#!/bin/sh
bbb-record --rebuildall
```

Ensure your script is runable `chmod +x /home/sysadmin/rebuild`

Edit your systemd service to remove `restart=always` and `exit 0`

```
[Unit]
Description=bbb-rebuild

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/sysadmin/rebuild

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then simply enable your systemd-timer with `systemctl enable rebuild.timer`.
Then check the timer is enabled with `systemctl status rebuild.timer`.

Comment: Why `sudo` instead of simply running the service as the correct user?

Comment: You're right, it is better to specify a user to run the service with, if nothing is specified the script is  run as `root`, so sudo is this case useless