# Getting hidden characters after extracting

Tags: bash, scripts, dash-shell

I'm trying to extract value after `Colon` in a string  which will be integer value later to compare, but I see `$` and `\r` after extracting, so I'm not able to compare integers

Ex:

```
count=$(echo "Bengaluru:10" | awk -F":" '{print $2}')
```

Result will be `10` only, but actually it's having additional hidden characters like `$'10\r'`

So I'm not able to compare this value with some other integer.

Please help me, how can i remove those values `$` and `\r`

Comment: One of your files (probably the script file) is in DOS/Windows format, and has a carriage return at the end of each line. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481278/syntax-error-invalid-arithmetic-operator-error-token-is) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) on stackoverflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invisible space when trying to remove file (but exclude all files in a list)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183866/invisible-space-when-trying-to-remove-file-but-exclude-all-files-in-a-list)