# How to move some files to their parent directory?

Tags: command-line, files, directory, find, mv

I want to pull all mp3's that accidentially have been put into a flac folder out of it, to their parent folder.

It should not matter how deep the folders are, **I just want to move the matching files exactly one directory up.**

Here's how I select my files:

```
find . -path "*/flac/*" -name '*.mp3'
```

This works from my music folder, but I am stuck here. All solutions I have found, either move the files to the parent of the current folder, or require some fixed structure.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -path "*/flac/*" -name '*.mp3' -execdir mv -t ../ {} +
```

#### How it works

1. `find .`

   Start a find command working on the current directory.
2. `-path "*/flac/*"`

   Select only files with `flac` in their path
3. `-name '*.mp3'`

   Select only files with extension `.mp3`.
4. `-execdir mv -t ../ {} +`

   For any files found run the `mv` command from the directory that the file is in and move the file to the parent directory.

   In addition to making this particular task easy, the option `-execdir` is also more secure than than the traditional `-exec` option.

#### Simplification

```
find . -path "*/flac/*.mp3" -execdir mv -t ../ {} +
```

Comment: Nice! Does exactly what I want.

Comment: Is the + an alternative for the ritualistic  \; ?

Comment: @Johnn1024 assuming there is no nested directories with same `flac` in path like `*/flac/flac/x.mp3` otherwise `x.mp3` file will move two level up.

Comment: @rackandboneman see [What is the difference between using '+' (plus) and ';' (semicolon) in -exec command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/558817/283843)