# Navigate directory and move files one level up, recursively

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have many directory with different name, each of them contain a subdirectory named httpd-ack (same name for all of them) in which are stored files.

I need a command to recursively enter each directory, enter subdir httpd-ack, move all files one level up and then delete the httpd-ack folder (which is empty now).

**start is**

*name1/httpd-ack/(files)*

*name2/httpd-ack/(files)*

*name3/...[...]*

**ending should be**

*name1/(files)*

*name2/(files)*

*name3....[...]*

Any help will be much appreciated....

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend you **[edit]** to clarify: *(1)* Does this have to operate recursively, where `http-ack` directories may be nested very deeply (e.g. `name4/foo/bar/baz/http-ack`)? *(2)* If so, should `http-ack` directories residing *inside* other `http-ack` directories be processed? Based on your examples, I *think* that this does not need to operate recursively and that you already have a list of all the directories (shown in the question as `name1`, `name2`, etc.). But I'm not totally sure and Jos has interpreted the question as requiring recursion so I figured I'd check.

Comment: Right question.  The httpd-ack subdir is nested only one level down, so maxdepth 1 is to be added to find command

Comment: @EliahKagan I believe the duplicate I picked solves the question but it would be great if you could confirm.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Although the question here is described in a way that makes it seem recursive ("recursively enter each directory"), what's actually needed here [is nonrecursive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245175/navigate-directory-and-move-files-one-level-up-recursively#comment2100293_1245175). It's something of a judgment call, as to whether this and [How to move some files to their parent directory?](https://askubuntu.com/q/988472/22949), and their answers, are similar enough for this to be considered a duplicate. I would not consider this to be a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Jos, this worked for me:

1. Create a file named `movefiles.sh` (and set it executable) with the following code:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   path=$1
   echo "Now processing $path" 
   cd "$path" 
   if [ -d "./httpd-ack" ]; then 
    cd httpd-ack 
           mv * ../ 
           cd .. 
           rmdir httpd-ack 
       fi
   ```
2. Invoke find as follows:

   ```bsh
   find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ./movefiles.sh {} \;
   ```

It worked like a charm...  (I didn't try @bac0n solution.)

Comment: The indenting shown in your script is unusual, and I wondered if maybe that was unintentional, but I kept it as it was just in case. If you're willing for it to be improved, you may want to **[edit]** this (or, if for some reason you don't want to do that, you could ping me by including `@EliahKagan` in a comment here and I'll edit it).

Answer (score 0):

This script should be a good start:

```
#!/bin/bash

moveFiles () {
    path=$1
    echo "Now processing $path"
    cd "$path"
    if [ -d "./httpd-ack" ]; then
        cd httpd-ack
        mv * ../
        cd ..
        rmdir httpd-ack
    fi
}

find top/level/dir -type d -exec moveFiles {} \;
```

First, it defines a function `moveFiles` that moves into the `httpd-ack` directory (if one is present) and moves all files upwards, then `cd`s up and deletes the now empty `httpd-ack`.

Then it finds all directories, starting from `/top/level/dir`, and calls the newly defined function on each of them.

I'm sure this could be improved. Editors, feel free.

Comment: Has this been tested? *`-exec` only runs external commands*, and `moveFiles` is a shell function. When I replace `top/level/dir` with a valid path and run it, I get `find: ‘moveFiles’: No such file or directory` (as expected). If this seems to work, all I can think of is maybe you originally wrote `moveFiles` as a script and put it in a directory in your `$PATH`? (You encouraged edits, but fixing this would be a major change. Also, I'm not sure how to make this method work properly: it looks like `dir/http-ack/http-ack` may be skipped, depending on the order in which `find` enumerates `dir`.)

Comment: as been stated above by @Eliah, the script doesn't execute the function call.
I put the code for MoveFiles in a separate script, and called it with:

find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ./movefiles.sh {} \;

and it worked!!!
TNX!

Comment: Please Gianluca, write your solution in an answer, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @EliahKagan No I hadn't tested it. In fact I had forgotten that `find` uses a new shell for the `exec` parameter, therefore cannot use the function definition. Gianluca's solution is what is needed.

Comment: you need to call your function with *bash -c* example *function f(){ echo helo; }; find -type f -exec bash -c f \;* ... find does not start a shell therefor no function are available