# delete specified lines in files under directories

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a directory, and it has many sub-directories.

> home/folderA/* 
>   home/folderB/*

What I want to do is to delete all lines that have certain text 'password' in files in each sub-directory.

```
sed -i '/password/d' *
```

this command can only work with files and can't go inside directories.
I'd be thankful for any advice in how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `find` with `sed` like:

```
find /path/to/source -type f -exec sed '/password/d' {} +
```

Add `-i` to `sed -i '/password/d'` above to write the changes into files in place.

- the `/path/to/source` is your directory path that you want to run `sed` for the files in and its sub-directories.
- the `-type f` looks for the **f**iles type only.
- with `-exec command {} +`, the *command* will be executed for the files found.

See and read also [What is the difference between using '+' (plus) and ';' (semicolon) in -exec command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/558817/283843).