# Copy all files from one folder to another in linux

Tags: cp

I want to copy only files not folders from one folder to another in linux. I am using the following command

```
cp sourceDir/* destDir
```

The above command does copy all files to `destDir` but the command does not stop processing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not stop processing"? the `cp` command should not copy folders unless you add the `-r` option

Comment: I mean command does not end, when i go to the destination folder, the files are copied there but, command does not finish

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

You can try the following trick and change your command to

```
cp sourceDir/*.* destDir
```

it will only copy files in the same folder, as long as they have the format like `filename.ext`. Make sure you have not folder with the same format.

### Option 2

Otherwise you try the following command:

```
find /sourceDir/ -type f -execdir cp "{}" /destDir/ ";"
```

It will search for all files inside the sourceDir and then copies them to the destDir.

Comment: you can do `find /sourceDir/ -type f -execdir cp -t /destDir/ {} +` to avoid call `cp` command for every single file found. see [What is the difference between using '+' (plus) and ';' (semicolon) in -exec command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/558817/283843)

Comment: this won't preserve hierarchy structure

Comment: first command only copy files, not copying folders and subfolders